# Marshall an array of managed strings to char*[]

Tags: marshalling, command-line-interface, unmanaged

What I would like to do is call an unmanaged C++ function from managed C++:

```
int runConfig(int argc, char* argv[])

public: static bool CreateConfigurationFile(int parameters, array<String^>^ arguments)
```

My question is how do I convert a managed array of managed strings into an unmanaged array of char*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

bool CreateConfigurationFile(int parameters, array<String^>^ arguments)
{
    int length = arguments->Length;
    char** argv = new char*[length];

    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        argv[i] = (char*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(arguments[i]).ToPointer();
    }

    runConfig(length, argv);

    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr(argv[i]));
    }

    delete[] argv;

    return true;
}
```

Notice that `int parameters` is not used, because .NET array has `Length` property.

If you want to call `runConfig` using PInvoke, use the following PInvoke declaration:

```
int runConfig(int argc, IntPtr argv);
```